# Cumulative distribution of linear combination of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Let $F_X$ be the cumulative distribution of $X$, and $F_Y$ be the cumulative distribution of $Y$. Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $a+b=1$. Then what can I say about the distribution of the random variable $Z := aX+bY$. Is it simply $aF_X + bF_Y$? Or do I need to assume something further?

Comment: No, you can't. You have to use the definition to derive it. $F_Z(z)=P(Z\le z)=P(aX+bY\le z)$

Comment: Distribution of $Z$ can be determined under independence of $X$ and $Y$. In general you can say nothing about distribution of $Z$.

Comment: What about under independence, can the cumulative distribution be deduced?